# Empty device properties in DirectShow

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

I am using DirectShow.Net to enumerate DirectShow devices like this:

```
var devices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.AudioInputDevice);
```

This code returns the expected number of audio devices but all of the items returned have null names and other properties:

```
devices[0]
{DirectShowLib.DsDevice}
    ClassID: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    DevicePath: null
    Mon: null
    Name: null
```

I have confirmed the devices are properly registered with GraphStudioNext and I know the audio devices are working in general. And I have the same issue with other devices like `FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice`.

Any ideas?

.Net Version: 4
Build target: 64 bit
OS: Win 10